# can I multi-partition s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have this data that was set up by someone else on S3…

The data is visitors data… with columns like VisitorId, Partner, Date, etc…

The data is partitioned by day (the people that owns it, query mostly by date)… But I wanted to query it too from Athena, and most of my queries tend to group by VisitorId, so I shall query/scan every, day, year,month…

My questions are:

- I was told I can’t/shouldn’t query by any other than date, I mean I must have ‘date’ in the ‘where’ clause… is this true?
- Can I index by VisitorId (as if it were a non-clustered index in sql server).
- Is my only option to load the data all over again, but this time partitioned by VisitorId?

Notice that the data as it is now partitioned by day, suits well for the people using it now… I just happened to need the same data but I want to query it differently…

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is partitioned by date, then queries that use `WHERE date BETWEEN xxx` will be very efficient, because only some directories need to be read.

However, you can still query by `VisitorId` or whatever you wish. It's just that Athena will need to scan all the partitions to find the data.

You can't "index" the columns. There's no such concept for this type of data storage.

If you are going to do lots of queries, I would recommend convert it into Parquet format. It would provide very efficient (and lower-cost) queries. The cost of storing the data twice (in different formats) would be minimal compared to the cost savings from running Amazon Athena queries over flat data.

See:

- [Converting to Columnar Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html)
- Cost savings: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @John Rotenstein's answer,

> I was told I can’t/shouldn’t query by any other than date, I mean I
>   must have ‘date’ in the ‘where’ clause… is this true?

Yes, if you structure your S3 bucket as such.

```
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-01-01/
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-01-02/
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-01-03/
...
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-06-07/
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-06-08/
```

You then stick all of the files with data corresponding to a given date under the bucketname and partition.

You then write DDL to use this partition:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE somedatabase.sometable (
  VisitorId bigint,
  Partner string,
  `Date` date, 
  ...
  fieldn typen
)
PARTITIONED BY (date_partition date)
ROW FORMAT ...
```

As @John Rotenstein says, you can then use the `date_partition` field in your where clause.  Notice that I used a different name as you cannot have two columns with the same name.

Also, there used to be a soft limit of 20,000 partitions per Athena table.  I checked the documentation and did not find this limit.  Perhaps it has been lifted?  Checking the [AWS Service Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html) page, I did not see any mention of a limit with regards to the number of partitions allowed on an Athena table.

> Can I index by VisitorId (as if it were a non-clustered index in sql server).

Yes, the logic would be the same

> Is my only option to load the data all over again, but this time partitioned by VisitorId?

You can partition on VisitorId and date but you'll have to load the correct data into the correct partitions.

```
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-01-01/visitorid_partition=1000/
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-01-01/visitorid_partition=2000/
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-01-02/visitorid_partition=1000/
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-01-02/visitorid_partition=2000/
...
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-06-07/visitorid_partition=1000/
s3://BUCKETNAME/date_partition=2000-06-08/visitorid_partition=2000/
```

The DDL would be written as such:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE somedatabase.sometable (
  VisitorId bigint,
  Partner string,
  `Date` date, 
  ...
  fieldn typen
)
PARTITIONED BY (date_partition date, visitorid_partition bigint)
ROW FORMAT ...
```

Always keep in mind that compression and columnar formats will result in additional savings.  [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/) can help with these transformations.

**Further Reading:**

[AWS Documentation » Amazon Athena » User Guide » Working with Source Data » Partitioning Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html)